# Where is the main viewcontroller that is displayed in your iPhone app specified and told to become visible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on an iPhone app again and I'd like to setup one view to be seen before another. I've added the view to my window and have specified the viewcontroller code that I'd like to use, but I can't find where on earth xcode specifies which viewcontroller in the window is displayed first. I'm sure it must be something obvious. I thought that the appdelegate seemed logical, but I don't see it displayed there. Any help? :(

Comment: which **kind** of app are you building?  did you start with an Xcode template, like the one for a "single view application" or "tabbed view application"?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is in the UIApplication setup code.  Also try looking in your xib file as to the linkages setup there!!!

Without seeing more code or your setup, this is the best I can do!!!

Answer (score 0):

As you can open the MainWindow.xib file you can see the part on the windows that specifies that from which viewcontroller it is gona load. (Like "Loaded From "RootViewController""). From the inspector of the window there is an option called NIB Name that gives you a list of view controllers available in your project.Changing these will change the setting of from which view controller you want to begin your app.

Hope this will help you.